# How to add up numbers with same value in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

So if i have an number array:

```
a     b
1     2.5 
1     1.2 
3     2.5
4     0.4
6     3
3     1.2
```

i want to sum up numbers in column a with same value of of b in column 2, like this:

```
a   b
4   2.5 
4   1.2 
4   0.4
6   3
```

so as you can see 1 and 3 add up and became 4, because they have the same value of b which is 2 and also to the rest of the numbers, so how i will do that? thanks
(PS: my real data is combination of integers and decimal no. thanks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `A` to be the input array, you have two approaches to play with here.

**Approach #1**

A combination of [`accumarray`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) and [`unique`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) -

```
[unqcol2,~,idx] = unique(A(:,2),'stable')
[accumarray(idx,A(:,1)) unqcol2]
```

---

**Approach #2**

With [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
[unqcol2,~,idx] = unique(A(:,2),'stable')
[sum(bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@eq,idx,1:max(idx)),A(:,1)),1).' unqcol2 ]
```

Comment: sorry, i forgot to include decimal numbers, please wait and i will edit it.