# Averaging data that have similar properties in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sequence, average

I have imported data from a text file, the data is in two columns. Column1 is velocity and column2 is position.

Now the data in column2 is equally spaced, say every 0.05 meter. There are several measurements for each position, but these measurement data may vary in the number of rows, sometimes less and sometimes more, as the following example shows.

Now the data in the table spans several thousand rows. My question is: how to find and average the velocity data for each position without needing to do so manually?I think the solution strategy would involve a for loop to find how many points each position have between the lower limit and the upper limit of the position, but not sure how to practically do that!Your help is really appreciated.

PS. I have previously asked here a similar question, but the data was more uniform, this is a more general case. You can find my previous question here:
[Average of numbers in two consequetive sequences using Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34292776/average-of-numbers-in-two-consequetive-sequences-using-matlab)

```
velocityPosition
14.0       0
 7.0       0
 7.0       0
 8.0       0
13.0       0
12.0       0
14.0       0
 7.0       0
 7.0    0.05
11.0    0.05
 9.0    0.05
 7.0    0.05
10.0    0.05
 8.0    0.05
14.0    0.05
 6.0    0.05
11.0    0.05
11.0    0.05
12.0     0.1
 6.0     0.1
12.0     0.1
14.0     0.1
 9.0     0.1
 8.0     0.1
14.0     0.1
12.0     0.1
13.0     0.1
12.0     0.1
10.0     0.1
11.0     0.1
  …       …
  …       …
 8.0     2.0
12.0     2.0
12.0     2.0
13.0     2.0
 7.0     2.0
 7.0     2.0
 9.0     2.0
```

Comment: IIUC, You can tag second column numbers based on their uniqueness with the third output from `unique`. Then, feed these tags to `accumarray` with the first column as `weights` to get the grouped summations and thus the averages. Something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/a/28784030/3293881

Comment: @Divakar Thank you for your kind response. Can you please give me example of what you mean? I'm truly not that "very" friends yet with Matlab :)

Comment: I meant something like : `[unqcol2,~,idx] = unique(A(:,2)); out = [unqcol2 accumarray(idx,A(:,1),[],@mean)`. See if it works. Has to be a duplicate of some previous question, just can't find.

Comment: OH! I have not noticed the link you have provided at first! Now it works very fine =) Just needed one more function to count the number of occurrences of each element in the array, and after some search I found it
[a,b]=hist(x,unique(x)), where x is the index array (idx). 
hank you again @Divakar!

Comment: There you go! You just friended `hist`, `unique` and the mighty `accumarray` ;) Not a bad start huh!